# python unittest.TestCase.assertRaises not working

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to run tests on my 'add' function in Python but it is giving an error :

```
7
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_upper (__main__.TestStringMethods)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MaZee/PycharmProjects/andela/asdasd.py", line 22, in test_upper
    self.assertEqual("Input should be a string:", cm.exception.message , "Input is not a string:")
AttributeError: '_AssertRaisesContext' object has no attribute 'exception'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here's my code :

```
    import unittest

    def add(a,b):
        """
        Returns the addition value of a and b.
        """
        try:
          out = a + b
        except TypeError:
          raise TypeError("Input should be a string:")

        print (out)
        return



class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError) as cm:
           add(3,4)
           self.assertEqual("Input should be a string:", cm.exception.message , "Input is not a string:")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: You could use [`assertRaisesRegexp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegexp). Also, that function seems really weird - it returns nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message is telling you, your *assert raises* object has no attribute `exception`. To be more specific, this call:

```
cm.exception.message
```

`cm` is your assert object in this case, and because the code you are testing never actually raises, your `cm` object will not have the `exception` attribute you are trying to access.

Now, on to why this is happening. You are trying to test what happens when an `exception` is being raised in your `add` method, in order to raise a `TypeError`. However, if you look at your test case you are passing two valid integers in to the `add` method. You will not raise an exception because this is a valid test case.

For your unittest, you are looking to test what happens when you `raise` something, i.e. insert invalid data to the `add` method. Try your code again, but this time in your unittest, pass the following:

```
add(5, 'this will raise')
```

You will now get your `TypeError`.

You will also need to perform your assertion validation outside of the context manager:

```
def test_upper(self):
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError) as cm:
        add(3, 'this will raise')
    self.assertEqual("Input should be a string:", cm.exception.message, "Input is not a string:")
```

You will now have another problem. There is no `message` attribute. You should be checking simply `cm.exception`. Furthermore, in your `add` method your string is:

```
"Input should be a string:"
```

However, you are checking that it is:

```
"Input is not a string:"
```

So, once you correct your unittest to use `cm.exception`, you will now be faced with:

```
AssertionError: 'Input should be a string:' != TypeError('Input should be a string:',) : Input is not a string:
```

So, your assertion should check the exception string by calling `str` on the `cm.exception`:

```
self.assertEqual("Input should be a string:", str(cm.exception), "Input should be a string:")
```

So, your full test method should be:

```
def test_upper(self):
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError) as cm:
        add(3, 'this will raise')
    self.assertEqual("Input should be a string:", str(cm.exception), "Input should be a string:")
```

Comment: I think you also have to put that *outside* the `with` block

Comment: i just tried '  add(5, 'this will raise')  '  but this time there's no error, i'm getting 'Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK'

Comment: Look at my updated answer. You have to place the assertion check outside of the context manager. However, remember, your test passing is an indication that your exception checking works. You should not see anything raise. If you really want to see what is going on line by line, use your debugger in PyCharm by placing a breakpoint int he method and stepping over each line. You will see that it actually goes in to the exception block and will `raise`. But your unittest is looking to "pass" when the method "successfully" raises.

Comment: @MazinoSUkah You have more issues upon further inspection. Read my updated answer.

Comment: @idjaw i just read ur updated answer , thank u its working now !!

Comment: @idjaw pls in what situation would the message attribute be set ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123164/discussion-between-mazino-s-ukah-and-idjaw).

Comment: @MazinoSUkah There is *no* message attribute in the exception object. You should inspect the exception object to check what is actually available to you. Also, look at the docs at what is available to you. You will actually see that the message is in `cm.exception.args` as a tuple of args. I suggest reading through the documentation to get more accustomed with exceptions.