# Trying to assert something about an exception, but get an AttributeError?

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, assert

I really don't understand what this error refers to

```
AttributeError("'_AssertRaisesContext' object has no attribute 'exception'",).
```

I'm trying to write a function power that accepts two arguments, a and b and calculates a raised to the power b and raise a `TypeError` with the message `Argument must be integer or float` if the inputs are anything other that ints or floats.

this is my code:

```
def power(a, b):
    try :

      if b == 0:
        return 1
      elif b == 1:
        return a;
      else:
        return a*pow(a, b-1)

    except TypeError :
        print ('Argument must be integer or float')
```

and this is the code im using to test it :

```
from unittest import TestCase
class PowerTestCases(TestCase):
  def test_returns_correct_power(self):
    base, exp = 2, 3
    res = power(base, exp)
    self.assertEqual(res, 8, msg='Expected {}, got {}'.format(8, res))

  def test_return_1_when_exp_is_0(self):
    base, exp = 4, 0
    res = power(base, exp)
    self.assertEqual(res, 1, msg='A number power 0 should be 1')

  def test_return_0_when_base_is_0(self):
    base, exp = 0, 10
    res = power(base, exp)
    self.assertEqual(res, 0, msg='O power any number should be 0')

  def test_non_digit_argument(self):
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError) as context:
      base, exp = 'base', 'exp'
      res = power(base, exp)
      self.assertEqual(
        'Argument must be interfer or float',
        context.exception.message,
        'Only digits are allowed as input'
      )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python unittest.TestCase.assertRaises not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450098/python-unittest-testcase-assertraises-not-working)

Comment: Your function _does not raise_ an exception. It merely prints some string to standard output and returns `None` if bad types are passed. See duplicate for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues:

First of all, you are *not actually raising an exception*. `print()` writes data to the `stdout` file (usually connected to your terminal or console), that's not the same thing.

Use `raise`:

```
raise TypeError('Argument must be integer or float')
```

Next, you are putting the assertion at the wrong indentation level. The point of the `with assertRaises()` context manager is to catch the exception that the code in the `with` block raises. Any further code in that block then doesn't get executed; the exception exited the block.

You'll need to make the assertion about the message *after* the block. That way the `assertRaises` also notices if no exception was in fact raised and you get a more meaningful assertion error:

```
with self.assertRaises(TypeError) as context:
     base, exp = 'base', 'exp'
     res = power(base, exp)

self.assertEqual(
    'Argument must be interfer or float',
    context.exception.message,
    'Only digits are allowed as input'
)
```